# Windows cmd to launch virtual machine

Tags: batch-file, cmd, virtual-machine, virtualbox, password-protection

Is there any windows cmd to launch a password protected virtual machine.

As a part of automation, my requirement is to write a script which will launch a virtual machine by taking credentials like username and password from the script file itself.

Is there any cmd or script to perform this.kindly help me out from this...

Comment: Only if the virtual machine software that you are using accepts command line parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No I don't think so you might try [AHK](http://www.autohotkey.com/)